# Why not use PT as the unit for fonts and element size?

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, font-size

I am developing a cross-platform mobile app using jQueryMobile and PhoneGap. The first platform I am targeting is Android.

For Android app, developers are advised to use dp as the unit for font sizes. DP stands for density-independent pixels. Using it means your fonts get the same physical size (in inches, centimeters, or whatever) on the screen, no matter what screen density.

That's great. Now I wonder: if I specify everything in dp, as Android would want me to, will other browser platforms support this unit? I assume not.

That makes me wonder what's wrong with older ways of (or workarounds for) setting the font to a physically absolute size:

**1. PT: one pt is 1/72 of an inch.**

So it's a physically absolute size, right? That sounds too good to be true. If this is reliable and supported on all browsers and devices, why do anything else?

**2. EM: one em is defined as the size of the font for the document.**

So with PT, the size is absolute from the start. Using em as the font size unit, I would only have to set the font size for the document in such a way as to make it right for the screen (I could use Javascript for that). And if all else is specified in em, I'd be finished. Right?

**3. jQueryMobile***
In the meanwhile, I am using CSS media queries to detect the screen width and height and density, and use them to set a base font-size for the  element. After that, all font dimensions are in em. A lot of posts suggest that em should be used only for fonts, but if your app/site is all about text, wouldn't it make sense with all elements containing text to set the dimensions in em?

**4. Or...**

Is dp also supported by 'desktop' browsers and by iOS?

Comment: I'm not sure that your first assertion is correct.  Ems I believe will scale within their container.   This is why they are preferred.  There might be more to it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with PhoneGap, but my understanding of it is that it is a framework that runs html/css/js that you write in the built in browser on the phone (webview). So it allows you to create a html5 app that is run so it seems just like a native Android app.

The dp unit is something that is only available for native applications using native Android controls so it's nothing that can be accessed from web pages or web apps.

Since you are writing a HTML5 app you should stick with web technology for specifying all your sizes and using media queries to detect screen density and adapt sizes to that sounds like the way to go for you.